# What is the physical reason that a weak muscle means that its antagonistic muscle will tighten?

Tags: injury

I've read online (probably from these two sources [Athlean-X](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=NhlVYy1wkKQ) and [Mike](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=jwlYZGtQSZs&feature=youtu.be)) that when one has a tight muscle that the antagonistic muscle tightens up as a defense mechanism. What I am trying to understand is **why** the body does this. From my intuition it seems that tightening up just makes the tight muscle vulnerable to wanting to stretch it and snap it, so I can't imagine how tightening is a good idea biologically. Furthermore, even if I choose not to stretch it (which is the instinct) it doesn't inform me what the real issue is nor does it seem as a way to defend anything. Thus, how is tightening up defending anything? How does this (perhaps from an evolutionary perspective) make sense? Why does this happen?